# AWK command to print until end of line

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a quick question regarding the AWK command. I need the command to print until the end of the line on the same line, but then when it gets to the next line I need it to print on another line. The following example will provide better clarity.

Say I have a file:

```
0 1 2 3 This is line one
0 1 2 3 This is line two 
0 1 2 3 This is line three 
0 1 2 3 This is line four
```

I have tried the following and gotten the following results

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' fileName >> resultsExample1
```

I get the following in resultsExample1

```
This
is
line
one
This 
is 
line 
two 
And so on....
```

Example 2:

```
awk 'BEGIN {" "} {for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) printf $1}' fileName >> resultsExample2
```

for resultsExample2 I get:

```
This is line one This is line two this is line three This is line four
```

I have also tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {" "} {for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) printf $1}' fileName >> resultsExample3
```

But the results were the same as the previous one

In the end I want the following:

```
This is line one
This is line two 
This is line three
This is line four
```

I'm grateful for any help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In the example, all the lines have the same number of columns - is this always the case with your input?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may be more straight-forward to use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f5- file
This is line one
This is line two 
This is line three 
This is line four
```

This says: on space-separated fields, print from the 5th up to the end of the line.

If you happen to have multiple spaces in between fields, you may initially want to squeeze them with `tr -s' '`.

Comment: This will only work if there are is only exactly one space between fields.

Comment: That's true, @Scrutinizer, but in case there were more than one we could firstly pipe `| tr -s ' '` to delete multiple spaces.

Comment: How would you handle this if the number of spaces (the delimiter) varied from one record to the next?  For example applying this to the output of `ls -l`?

Comment: @gone I should see this in more detail, but [parsing `ls` is not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @fedorqui, I didn't mean to divert the conversation to the topic of whether parsing `ls` is a good idea or not.  The point is that in some outputs, the delimiter can be elastic.

Comment: @gone agreed. For such non-standard inputs, I always use `tr -s` to `s`queeze those delimiters.

Comment: @fedorqui `tr -s ' '` saved me!

Comment: caveat programmer: whilst `tr -s ' '` may be a help with the cut on the fields, it will also collapse spaces in the trailing remainder of the line, thus modifying it.

Answer (score 27):

I know this question is very old, but another awk example:

```
awk '{print substr($0,index($0,$5))}' fileName
```

What it does:
find the index where you want to start printing (index of $5 in $0) and print the substring of $0 starting at that index.

Caveat:
As stated in comments, this will faill if `$5` is not unique in prior fields.

Comment: It works if `$5` has a value which is not found in previous fields. If this is the case (and it was for me :-), I think it is the most readable solution.

Comment: This is extremely useful when we're working on block levels (not lines):
`top -1 -bSHEk -u yarn | awk -v RS='top - ' -v FS='\n' '{print substr($0,index($0,$14))}'` would nicely print every line after the line you intend within a single block!

Comment: Dangerous. As @MatM implies, this solution fails if the one of fields 1 through 4 are identical to field 5. Consider this input `a man a plan a canal panama`.

Answer (score 10):

OR with awk

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=""; sub(/^  */,"", $0); print }'  awkTest2.txt
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
This is line four
```

Also, you're solution is almost there, you just need to force a '\n' to be printed at the end of each processed line, i.e.

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) {printf $i " "} ; printf "\n"}' awkTest2.txt
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
This is line four
```

Note that your `BEGIN { " " }` is a no op. And you should use `$i` instead of `$1` to print the current iterations value.

IHTH.

**Edit** ; Noting sudo_O objection, I added a %s to the data. Here is the output

```
This is line one
This is line two
This is line three
T%shis is line four
```

This may be a problem for you, so it that case read about how to pass a format string to printf.

Comment: You should not use `printf` without specifying the format. What do you think will happen if one the fields contains `%s` for example?

Comment: I agree with sudo_O. You should get `awk: not enough args in printf(T%shis )` for example..

Comment: I'm got making up my output. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a solution using awk as well!

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{gsub (/[[:digit:]]/,"");{$1=$1}}1' file`

Answer (score 0):

**`sed` provides the best solution to this problem**.

The accepted cut-based solution has the problem that, unlike awk, it assumes there is exactly one space between fields.

The usual fix of using `tr -s ' '` to squeeze multiple adjacent spaces into one space is problematic too: it would collapse spaces in the trailing remainder of the line, thus modifying it, as @inopinatus commented.

The following sed-based solution will achieve our goal while preserving spaces in the remainder of the line:

```
sed -E 's/^([^ \t]*[ \t]*){4}//' <<'EOF'
0 1 2 3 This is line one
0 1 2 3 This is line two   test of extra spaces
0 1 2 3 This is line three
0 1 2 3 This is line four
EOF
```

Result:

```
This is line one
This is line two   test of extra spaces
This is line three
This is line four
```

We simulated awk's default behavior of delimiting fields by sequences of whitespace.

> Fields are normally separated by whitespace sequences (spaces, TABs, and newlines)
> – [Default Field Splitting (The GNU Awk User’s Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html)